# Django template replace text returned from model with local image

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I have have a model which I am pulling data from and adding it into a table on my page. There is a particular field I am returning which contains a combination of 64 version of `{x}`. Replacing each version with a corresponding image.

For example, the data is returned in the format of `{B}`, `{B}{U}`,`{B}{B}`,`{1}{W}{R}`. There are 64 different version of `{x}` which could be arranged in any combination. I have corresponding `.png` files for each version, and I am trying to replace the text with the image.

My code below only works if there is an single instance of a version, however I also think it would be very inefficient if I were to do this for each of the 64 versions. It doesn't work if there are multiple of the same version, eg. `{B}{B}`

Is there a way I could loop through each one and replace it with the correct image.

**html**

```html
<td class="">
  {% if "{B}" in card.colors %}<img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/symbology/{B}.png' %}">{% endif %}
  {% if "{G}" in card.colors %}<img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/symbology/{G}.png' %}">{% endif %}
  {% if "{R}" in card.colors %}<img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/symbology/{R}.png' %}">{% endif %}
  {% if "{U}" in card.colors %}<img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/symbology/{U}.png' %}">{% endif %}
  {% if "{W}" in card.colors %}<img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/symbology/{W}.png' %}">{% endif %}
  ...
</td>
```

**Update:**

There are 64 version of `{x}`, for example `{1}`,`{2}`,`{3}`,`{4}`,`{5}`, etc. The 64 version are singular. So each version has a corresponding img.

However each single version can be in any combination.

**For example:**

if the returned data is `{R}` it should be replaced with the following image:

[image]

However if the data returned is `{R}{R}{R}` it should be replaced with:

[image]
[image]
[image]

So it would get the image three times.

The character and curly brackets corresponds with the the name of the image. Hence the above should be replace with three `<img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/symbology/{R}.png' %}">`

This needs to be dynamic as many records are return for the model and the data returned could be any combination of `{x}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to work it out.

I first loop through the model field `card.colors`, which returns the character needed for the `.png` files.

In this loop, I then render an image using `i` from the loop.

```html
<td class="">
  {% for i in card.colors %}
      <img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/symbology/{'|add:i|add:'}.png' %}">
  {% endfor %}
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your question but did you try looping through the images and concatenating them with the rest of the image URL?
I would try something like:

```
{% for combo in card.colors %}
<img class="icon" src="{% static 'img/symbology/{{ combo }}.png' %}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I have updated the question, hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: So say it returns {5}, you want that image to be rendered 5 times?  And also what data type exactly does the model return. Is it an int or string?

Comment: so if it returned `{5}` it would be replaced by the `{5}.png` image. The datatype is `character varying[]` in postgres.

Comment: And if it returns {R}{R}{R} you want the image rendered 3 times? This part is a little confusing to me because it returns a string and you want it to render the image based on the length/ size of the data returned

Comment: Correct. I think this is why I'm having issues with it as I need to split it and then use each `{x}` to render the correct corresponding image.